# ntpdate - no server suitable for synchronization found

Tags: linux, centos, ntpdate

I have a newly installed Centos 5.2 box, everything seems working except ntpdate sync, I have done enable port 123 UDP to pass through the firewall. I have tried to use -u for unprivileged ports but still keeps throwing this error "no server suitable for synchronization found". Can anyone there help?

Comment: What is in your `/etc/default/ntpdate` and `/etc/ntp.conf` files? What happens if you do `ntpdate -q ntp.ubuntu.com`? What happens if you run `ntpdate` with `sudo`?

Comment: Have you also allowed the response packet back _in_ through the firewall?

Comment: Yes, its enabled out and in

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a NTP server configured? ntpdate will display that error message if you don't have one... try

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

for starters.

Comment: Using the public NTP pool is the way to go.  Even better if you isolate it to the continent you are on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to sync with an internal NTP server to sort out firewall problems (every Windoze Domain Controller is also an NTP server, or install `ntpd` using `yum`).